# Pandas - Create Dictionary out of columns and row groups quickly

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to quickly make a dictionary out of groups of values where each element in the dictionary has a key value pair from two other columns associated with that value. For example:

My data:

```
                 cheese               x               y
 1  0000000000000005559               1               2
 2  0000000000000005559               2               2
 3  0000000000000004058               3               5
 4  0000000000000004058               4               5
 5  0000000000000004058               5               5
```

Desired output:

```
cheese
0000000000000005559              {1: 2, 2: 2}
0000000000000004058        {3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 5}
0000000000000007157              {6: 7, 7: 7}
0000000000000000815    {8: 10, 9: 10, 10: 10}
0000000000000009160          {11: 12, 12: 12}
```

I can do this with an overly complicated `lambda` and `apply` but that is really slow with larger dataframes (order of millions of unique groupings). How can I achieve this quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way using `defaultdict`
This should be pretty fast

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

es = df.epoch.values.tolist()
xs = df.x.values.tolist()
ys = df.y.values.tolist()

for e, x, y in zip(es, xs, ys):
    d[e][x] = y

pd.Series(d)

1505339100449045559          {1: 2, 2: 2}
1505339102148504058    {3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 5}
dtype: object
```

Comment: This ones fast.  Sir you can add timings na

Comment: I tested it and got (in seconds):
`Out[84]: 6.7047929763793945`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [1544]: df.groupby('epoch').apply(lambda x: dict(x[['x', 'y']].values))
Out[1544]:
epoch
1505339100449045559          {1: 2, 2: 2}
1505339102148504058    {3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 5}
dtype: object
```

same as `df.groupby('epoch')[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))`

and  from [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587971/pandas-create-dictionary-out-of-columns-and-row-groups-quickly#comment80129268_46588007) `df.groupby('epoch').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['x'], x['y'])))`

---

Timings

```
In [1585]: ndf = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

In [1587]: %timeit ndf.groupby('epoch').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['x'], x['y'])))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.65 ms per loop

In [1586]: %timeit ndf.groupby('epoch')[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.9 ms per loop

In [1588]: %timeit ndf.groupby('epoch').apply(lambda x: dict(x[['x', 'y']].values))
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is basically what I had and is really not fast. I time it in a sec and post the results.